# Highest number of Smallest numbers Haskell

Tags: haskell

So i have a list of lists, and i have to get out the minimum of every list and get the maximum of the minimums

EXAMPLE:

maximumOfMinimums [[1], [3, 5, 4], [8, 2]] == 3

This is how i tried:

```
maxMin :: [[a]] -> a
maxMin (x:xs) = minimum(map maximum (x:xs))
```

Comment: Ok, so what is your question?

Answer (score 5):

You did it the other way around. Here you are calculating the minimum of the maximums of every list. Furthermore there is a problem with the signature: you need to add a type constraint that `a` is an instance of the `Ord` typeclass:

```
maxMin :: Ord a => [[a]] -> a
maxMin xs = maximum (map minimum xs)
```

or as a point-free expression:

```
maxMin :: Ord a => [[a]] -> a
maxMin = maximum . map minimum
```

Note that this will *not* work if the list is empty, or one of the sublists is empty.